# Careers 2.0 Broken Jobs by Employer Link

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The following page produces an empty response:
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/employer/AD:60

I'm thinking it may have something to do with the colon in their name? I checked some other [jobs by employers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/employer/Kiersted%20Systems) pages and they all seem to work. But do not have colons in their names.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, it is related to the colon.  We're looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.  The URL is now: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/employer/AD_60